# Does NSTimeZone in iPhone adjust automatically for DST

Tags: iphone, dst, nstimezone

I have a fairly simple question. I have a set of dates in UTC. I want to represent these to the user in the correct local time adjusted (or not, if DST is not currently in effect) for DST.

So, if I do something such as the following, will timeStamp be set correctly to the local time in New York taking DST into account when in effect

```
NSDate *date = initialise with a UTC time

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/New_York"];
    [formatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSString *timeStamp = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Or so I need to do something else? Do I check NSTimeZone.isDaylightSavingTime/NSTimeZone.daylightSavingTimeOffset and adjust my date accordingly or anything like that?

Thanks in advance?

Twibbles.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `NSDateFormatter` will automatically adjust for DST if you create the timeZone with `[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName]`. `NSTimeZone` knows the DST rules for each time zone and can look into the future and the past and will do the right thing for the `NSDate` passed to `stringForDate`. However, if you create the `NSTimeZone` with `[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT]` DST adjustments are not made. It should also be noted that DST rules are subject to change, which means `NSTimeZone` is not guaranteed to always do the right thing for all time zones.

You do not need to use `NSTimeZone.isDaylightSavingTime` or `NSTimeZone.daylightSavingTimeOffset` to format an `NSDate` as DST correct local time. Both of those methods operate on the current time. If you want to know if an `NSDate` falls within DST in a timezone you can use the `NSTimeZone.isDaylightSavingTimeForDate` method and if you want to know what the DST offset is for an NSDate you can use the `NSTimeZone.daylightSavingTimeOffsetForDate` method.